# Bigquery: How to write Multiline SQL UDF?

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to create a SQL UDF in bigquery where I could perform certain operations and then return the value.

For eg, In SQL Server, I could create a UDF as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION east_or_west (
    @long DECIMAL(9,6)
)
RETURNS int AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @return_value int;
    SET @val = 5;
    IF (@long > 0.00) SET @val = 10;
    IF (@long < 0.00) SET @val = 20;
    SET @ModelID = (SELECT count(*) 
                  FROM MODELS m
                 WHERE m.areaid = @val)
 
    RETURN @ModelID
END;
```

How would I go around implementing this simple multiline sql udf in bigquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below

```
CREATE FUNCTION east_or_west(long float64) as ((
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM `project.dataset.MODELS` m
  WHERE m.areaid = (
    CASE 
      WHEN long > 0.00 THEN 10
      WHEN long < 0.00 THEN 20
      ELSE 5
    END
  )
));
```

Comment: Hi @Mikhail. This was just an example function. I wanted to create an SQL UDF where I could declare variables, perform some operations, maybe run a select query etc. It seems like that is not possible in SQL UDF?

Comment: you should use stored proc for this!

Comment: Hi @Mikhail. Is there no way to have multi line sql udfs? It is my understanding that: 1. We can write functions using either sql or js language. 2. But if we choose the sql language then in that case, it can only be a 1 line sql expression, correct? 3. If we decided to use JS udfs, then we cannot have statments like: let a = "SELECT count(*) FROM emp"; <perform some operations according to the value of a>; return someVar; in JS udfs, correct?

Comment: kind of yes! if you need to package script with multiple sql statements - you use stored proc. if it is just one select statement (no matter how complex it is  - but it is one) you can use SQL UDF. and finally - you can use JS UDF where you can use power of javascript with some limitations - documentation is pretty good - check it out :o)